# Cannot Parse Libraries In Linux Using Qt Enviornment

Tags: qt, opencv, qt-creator

After some helpful tips this is the new version of this post, the thing is that it seems my programs is somehow running but it just issues some errors...i don't know what is it actually mentioning, because the libraries are installed, i changed the path form LIBS += -`LC:/usr/local/lib/ \` to `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \` as some one said it's actually refering to windows while u r using linux(chakra) and then added "\" at the end of directories and added pkg-config to my .pro file , so this is the new version of a new problem... :

```
    Starting /home/lucifer/PR0J3CTs/FirstOpenCV-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_2_in_PATH__System__Release/FirstOpenCV...
/home/lucifer/PR0J3CTs/FirstOpenCV-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_2_in_PATH__System__Release/FirstOpenCV exited with code 0

Debugging starts
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtTest.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtTest.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtNetwork.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtXml.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtXml.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtSvg.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtSvg.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
the debug information found in "/usr/lib/libQtDBus.so.4.8.2.debug" does not match "/usr/lib/libQtDBus.so.4" (CRC mismatch).
Debugging has finished
```

this is my .pro Configurations [ As U can see I've commented (#) one of two LIBS configs, I just wanted to ask which could be more accurate or more helpful, yesterday i tried and it issued some incompatibility with newer version of libavcodec so I googled some and downloaded libavcodec.53 and configured it but I'm uncertain what should happen now , I'm Now at the moment trying to get the opencv-qt-for-all package from ccr community repository and let the program handle these issues by it self, but I'm sure it won't fix my problem] :

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = FirstOpenCV
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
CONFIG   += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2/

#LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
#-libopencv_core.so \
#-libopencv_highgui.so \
#-libopencv_imgproc.so \
#-libopencv_features2d \
#-libopencv_calib3d.so

LIBS += /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so \
/usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so \
/usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so \
/usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so \
/usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so \
/usr/lib/libavcodec.so
```

And here's The Code :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main() {

    // read an image
    Mat image = imread("002.jpg");
    // create image window named "My Image"
    namedWindow("My Image");
    // show the image on window
    imshow("My Image", image);
    // wait key for 5000 ms
    waitKey(5000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should mention that the first LIBS [the commented # one ] issues that there is no such libs, but the seconds one is compiled and opens a new terminal and it seems it's just cannot show that image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved , as i said before , my program executed but with an error the problem was the Picture Directory, i've put it in the source file beside main.cpp the problem is that if u want to get a real result Using Debug Or Release Mode u should actually put the picture in those two directories and then run Make another time.

If u are willing to run it through the same directory that i used which was the source file, u should open an terminal or just press F4 in ur Dolphin File Manager or whatever u use and first run `qmake` then call the `make` and u are good to go, another problem was my OS (chakra) won't let mounted devices to have an Executable Permission so u have to move ur project to Home or Where ever u prefer inside the environment of ur OS.

SOLVED...:) Tnx every one:)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = FirstOpenCV
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2/

LIBS += -LC:/usr/local/lib/ \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it fails on your LIBS declaration.

Can you try this:

```
LIBS += -LC:/usr/local/lib/ \
    -libopencv_core.so.2.4.2 \
    -libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.2 \
    -libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.2 \
    -libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.2 \
    -libopencv_calib3d.so.2.ss4.2
```

Please notice the backslashes at the end of the lines. Without those, the next line is parsed as a separate declaration and "-libopencv_core.so.2.4.2" by itself is not a valid declaration.

Comment: I fixed what u mentioned , tnx but it didn't fix my problem it still issues an error Saying "[Makefile] error 2" : File Not Found"

Comment: Your commands are wrong.  That will make the compiler look for libibopencv_core.so.2.4.2.  It should be just -lopencv_core.so.2.4.2

Comment: um...i dont see any lib''ib''opencv_core.so.2.4.2 in my commands & i think u r wrong because it doesn't issue any problem...

Comment: @T0MXeOnLuCiFeR: Am I right in saying that it fixed the error you were originally reporting? You seem to be getting a different error now... Can you paste the complete output you're getting now?

Comment: @T0MXeOnLuCiFeR: I don't want to dissuade you, but the update you did to your question indicates you have proceeded but now face a completely different problem. As you now have a running executable the original problem with the .pro file should be fixed. Please mark the answers that have helped you as appropriate, and post a new question for the problem you may have with using OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen using C:/ on Unix: then this could be a required correction (also accounts for @enderland answer):

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highgui \
-lopencv_imgproc \
-lopencv_features2d \
-lopencv_calib3d
```

I had some problem on my system when upgraded to OpenCV 2.4.2 - The *runtime* was bound to previous version, bundled with the OS. I had to (painfully) recompile and reinstall OpenCV, and in the way I found a nice 'trick': use pkgconfig instead of hard coding the paths:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```